# Excel VBA Send Email

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want a macro to send the excel doc as the body of an email in outlook.  I tried recording a macro and sending it, but that didn't write any code.  I will be creating a batch file that will open excel on a scheduled time and I want the program I have in excel to run then to send the tabs "Assembly" "Lam" "Finish" and "MW" as the body of the email in outlook.  Is this even possible?

Comment: It is, you can start with modifying the code found [On http://www.rondebruin.nl](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail6.htm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [quick google](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel%20vba%20send%20sheet%20as%20email%20body) search would've gone a long way.

See: [How to send a range of cells in an e-mail message by using Visual Basic for Applications in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816644)

Here's the relevant VBA Code.

```
Sub Send_Range()

   ' Select the range of cells on the active worksheet.
   ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5").Select

   ' Show the envelope on the ActiveWorkbook.
   ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True

   ' Set the optional introduction field thats adds
   ' some header text to the email body. It also sets
   ' the To and Subject lines. Finally the message
   ' is sent.
   With ActiveSheet.MailEnvelope
      .Introduction = "This is a sample worksheet."
      .Item.To = "E-Mail_Address_Here"
      .Item.Subject = "My subject"
      .Item.Send
   End With
End Sub
```

For your particular case, you will have to modify above code to select all cells for each of the 4 sheets - `"Assembly"` `"Lam"` `"Finish"` and `"MV"` in a loop and stick it into the email body.